# SSRS: Display image from varbinary column in the database

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

My apologies if I've missed something, but from what I've found here on SOF as well as other sites, I cannot find my issue as having been discussed. I need to display an image that exists in SQL Server as a `varbinary` column.

```
SELECT 
    photo = CASE WHEN event_id = 47 THEN e.data ELSE NULL END
```

[image]

Here's the first 8 bytes: `0x2D00000030303030` and I've been told this is a JPEG.

My attempts so far include the following SSRS image setup:

[image]

However, I still get the red X in the report itself.

[image]

Now, I have seen the page that describes putting the images in a separate table, but I don't believe that's going to work for my purposes because I need an image to display in the same tablix with specific rows only. My current understanding of SSRS presumes only one data set per tablix, so I can't "combine" two tables into one tablix. Would the solution be to use this separate table approach, but then join with my existing dataset?

---

**EDIT 1:** Upon getting the pictures to show, I have erroneous red X's where nothing should be showing, probably on account of the expression I'm using. NOTE: It turned out to be base64 from which I had to decode. `System.Convert.FromBase64String(Fields!photo.Value)`

I have tried the following expression to get rid of the X's, but it doesn't work: `=iif(isnothing(Fields!photo.Value)=1,nothing,System.Convert.FromBase64String(Fields!photo.Value))`

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the following in the "Use this Field" expression

```
=System.Convert.ToBase64String(Fields!myImageColumn.Value)
```

I don't know if your image is of this type but I had the same issue many years ago and converting it using the above which worked. Also, try changing the MIME type to `image/png` just in case you have been misinformed.

**Edit after update from OP**

Now that the image issue has been resolved, you will still get a red x where you have no image to show. You could try two things.

1. Set the visibility of the image placeholder based on the image column content (empty or not). I can't see why would not work but just in case...
2. Add an empty image to the database and use that if no actual image exists.

Comment: Thanks. I'm pretty sure this is among the things I found and tried, but I tried it again, as well as with every other image type, but no luck.

Comment: I must admit I know very little about image headers etc but from a quick bit of research, I'm not entirely sure that you data column contains an image.. Do you have anything else (another report/app/tool) that has successfully rendered the content of this column as an image? If not there is a free trial of a tool that can do the job very easily, so you can at least be sure you have an image  https://www.yohz.com/siv8_details.htm

Comment: Your studiousness is so very appreciated lol as it turns out, the software developer who knows anything about these columns in this table didn't clarify fully the column I needed, which led to an assumption on my part (he said "data column", even though the right column was actually labeled "formatted_event_data"). I have the pictures showing now (YAY!) but the other rows are showing a red X and Id like to get rid of those if I could. I'll edit my question to provide some detail.

Comment: I've just added to my answer

Comment: Great idea. I was trying to get it to just give me the NULL (which would be blank in the row otherwise), but using the visibility was a good idea. That settles me up, thank you so much.